# How to login in youtube with loginClient (iOS app)

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, youtube, gdata

I develop **Youtube** app for iphone. One of my tasks - login on **Youtube**. I need *objective-c* sample for LoginClient Request and taking marker from it.

*Like this model of loginClient.*
[image]

**Very very Thank's!**

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)login:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"]];

NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Email=%@&Passwd=%@&service=youtube&source=&continue=http://www.google.com/",username,password];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];


NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
[request setTimeoutInterval:120];
NSData *replyData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];    

NSString *replyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:replyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"%@",replyString);



if([replyString rangeOfString:@"Auth="].location!=NSNotFound){
    authToken=[[replyString componentsSeparatedByString:@"Auth="] objectAtIndex:1];
    return YES;
}else{
    return NO;
}
}
```

I think this is what you need. This get the authentication token using ClientLogin scheme.